# No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3 and commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

My gradle settings are thus : [image: Gradle settings]

I have tried degrading the gradle build tool version to 2.3.2, have tried with both offline checked and unchecked and with both the default gradle wrapper and my local gradle installation. Nothing seems to work. The **make** on project runs successfully but **deploying** it fails with the following error (detailed):

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Project_Name'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1.
>        Required by:
>            project : > com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2 > org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1
>            project : > com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2 > org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2 > net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3 
>            project : > com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2 > org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2 > net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3 > commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0
>   No cached version of commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 available for offline mode.

Surprisingly, it deployed successfully the last time, which must have been a couple of weeks back. I did not do any configuration changes neither any updates to the Android Studio or related components. So I have no idea why this error has appeared out of the blue while deployment.

Edit 1: I have to mention that even though such questions exist on SO, none of the solutions mentioned there solved this issue. They were all suggesting disabling offline work, but it was never enabled in the first place in my project.

Edit 2 : Adding the gradle files:

1. Project gradle file:
   [image: Project gradle file]
2. App module gradle file:
   [App module gradle file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Qj6eCr02BELTlYUHBodWRpM00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it seems that you are working offline. You have to download at least once to work

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a transitive dependency issue. First are you targeting Oreo? if so, make sure you include the new google/maven repo pointer in your build.gradle file.

If not or if you have already done this, then try including the commons-logging 1.1.1 file that the bintry-plugin is requiring.

Are any of the dependencies listed in your yellow yours? Could just be a transitive dependency missing that needs either included or excluded.

Also make sure you have the correct gradle repos setup for pulling the 2.3.2. Can you share your project gradle file as well as your gradle.properties and your settings.gradle and any other applicable gradle file that you are using. I'm sure we can get you up and going again.

Resolving dependencies is a pain, but you can usually hunt it down if you do a bash gradlew assembleRelease --debug and see where/how the issue shows itself first.

Comment: Well, my compileSdk version is 25. So I am not targetting Oreo yet. How do I manually include the commons-logging 1.1.1 file . I mean, where should I download it?

Comment: // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.1'

Comment: Thanks. Although I was looking for where should I download it to, I mean, should it be in the maven_home directory? Also, I just checked that the commons jar is not my dependency, but the dependency of a few of the dependencies I have. So there should be no reason I should have to download it, also considering the fact that it was working all fine upto the last build.

Comment: yeah that is unusual. Have you tried reverting your changes to see if it builds again? Just seems like a transitive dependency is getting left out somehow to me.

Comment: Just cleaned the project and built again. It built and deployed successfully! What the heck? ALthough, after that, I got another weirdly unexpected error while running the app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554483/findviewbyidr-id-icon-returns-null , can you see if you have ever faced this issue? Anyway, thanks a lot for the help.