# findViewById(R.id.icon) returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid, androiddesignsupport, bottomnavigationview

`R.id.icon` is already defined in Android API level 1. However, I am getting an NPE in a `Android Design Support Library` internal code while accessing an imageview inflated using `R.id.icon`.

NOTE:  I **am not**  targetting Oreo as my `targetSdk` is currently `25` .

Here is the stacktrace:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.widget.ImageView.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
   at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView.setChecked(BottomNavigationItemView.java:172)
   at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView.initialize(BottomNavigationItemView.java:97)
   at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.buildMenuView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:276)
   at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationPresenter.updateMenuView(BottomNavigationPresenter.java:62)
   at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:238)
   at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:167)
   at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:116)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
  at com.who.android.app.layout.activities.Sample_Mock.onCreate(Sample_Mock.java:40) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

On investigation, I found out that the code in [BottomNavigationItemView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/BottomNavigationItemView.java) is trying to access a null `ImageView` inflated with `R.id.icon` resource.

```
            LayoutParams iconParams = (LayoutParams) mIcon.getLayoutParams();
```

where `mIcon` is `null` and has been inflated as

```
    mIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
```

Edit: I created a new `BottomNavigationActivity` from Android's Gallery and redirected the navigation to this mock class instead of mine. Still I am facing the same issue. Here are the pristine java code and the layout xml code for the new mocked activity :

```
package com.who.android.app.layout.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.who.android.app.R;

public class Sample_Mock extends AppCompatActivity {

  private TextView mTextMessage;

  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample__mock);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
  }

}
```

Here is the pristine layout file where I use the BottomNavigationView (as created by Android, I have not touched it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com._._._._.activities.Sample_Mock">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_home"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The version of Android Design Support Library and Android AppCompat support libraries I am using are both 25.3.1

```
com.android.support:design:25.3.1
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why I am getting a null reference out of inflating from R.id.icon ? This code is beyond my control as it is internal to the Android Design Support library. Also, as I showed that this problem occurs in a newly created `BottomNavigationActivity` as well, is there a problem with the library version I am using? Because this version has been working fine for last several months for me.

Edit 2: I created another project altogether with just one BottomNavigationActivity in it. Guess what? Same error there. So it seems to me do be an `Android Design Support` Library issue.

Edit 3: menu/navigation.xml As you can see, it is standard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: The NPE is occuring in the BottomNavigationItemView.java code, which is internal to Android internal framework. Please read the question properly before downvoting.

Comment: You can share java code you call xml?

Comment: Can you share your menu/navigation code. It appears to be improperly loading an imageview and then trying to set an icon to it somewhere. Just want to ensure it's not in the bottomNav view itself. Also, some assets are packaged with android so if you accidentally reuse an id like icon you may cause a conflict there as well.

Comment: @Sam, I included a sample code in my project from some website which was using id/icon. But I remember that I had deleted that code. Also on grepping and AndroidStudio search, I don't get any occurrences of "id/icon" in my entire source code, so I am sure I am not reusing the icon id.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all cache directories, build directories and maybe even your IDEA files and just do a fresh open of the project? Sometimes a fresh start clears things up. Never know

Comment: @Sam, I have done a reboot of OS -> rebuild, which should delete all the cached intermediates and also shuts down and restarts IntelliJ. Is there something else I could do to delete the cache directories?

Comment: @HasanSaykın what do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant you load "setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample__mock);" after navigationitem onclick listener. Maybe you should load layout before that?

Comment: It was before that previously. That didn't work either. So I had put it after the navigation item's stuff to check out. This didnt work either.

Comment: Anyways, as you can read in my edit, even a new project with just the pristine BasicNavigationActivity is causing this. So will have to create an issue with Google devs.

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/06/android-using-bottomnavigationview.html

Comment: The only new thing he had mentioned in the site is adding constraintLayout. As I had suspected, that didn't help.

Comment: Please post `@menu/navigation` xml.

Comment: @azizbekian, posted as requested.

Comment: Try commenting out your imageviews and then add them back one at a time in that menu nav and see if one of them is the offender

Comment: @Sam Commenting out all the menus worked. I uncomment any one menu item and this problem arises. I guess it makes sense because the problem is with the inflating of the image view representing a Menu item. From my understanding of the code, BottomNavigationItemView (where the NPE is arising from) represents a single menu item in the Android Design Support library. So if I comment all menu items, there is actually no BottomNavigationItemView, so the NPE throwing code does not execute. THe moment I include a menu item, it's mIcon doesn't inflate with R.id.icon, leading to NPE in setChecked func.

Comment: Ok next up, can you comment out just the icon line of each one and see if you get the text to show up at least with default placeholder imageviews in the bar. Then also try adding the menu items in code, just to really understand the issue and where / how the problem shows itself fully

Comment: @Sam, I know that the issue is with inflating any drawable with R.id.icon. It was easy to figure that out in the BottomNavigationItemView.java code. But I could not understand why that was happening. However, the google engineer asked me to upgrade the libraries to 26.1.0 and now it is working. So I am not sure what issue suddenly appeared in 25.3.1 to cause this bug. It is working now, anyway.

Comment: Excellent yes they occasionally have bugs so upgrading is never bad to check if the behavior is unexpected and wrong. Good job, glad you were able to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after increasing target API level to 31.

Due to requirement for [pending intents mutability](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability), I had to update Navigation dependency to [2.4.0-alpha04 or higher](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha04), so that pending intents created via [NavDeepLinkBuilder.createPendingIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder#createPendingIntent()) specify mutability. However, the application started crashing with an exception similar to yours.

**The solution was to replace** `R.id.icon` **with** `R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view`**.**